# How to determine whether the following series is convergent using d'Alembert criterion

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)}$

So we do this:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(n+1)\tan(\frac{\pi}{2 ^{n+2}})}{n\tan(\frac{\pi}{2 ^{n+1}})}$$

And then what?

Comment: Please do not just post the problem. Show us some of your work.

Comment: @Vanessa it shouldn't be something difficult. Probably I should do a simple step that will bring me to the solution

Comment: Please use mathjax and as Vanessa pointed out show us your thoughts and/or attempts, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll place here some hints:

*HINT 1*: ratio test implies calculation of $$\displaystyle L = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$$

*HINT 2*: for $\tan(x)$ function, we have the following approximation (for small enough $x$):
$$
\tan(x) \approx x 
$$

Now you can compute $L$ and compare it with $1$. If $L < 1$, then the series converges, if $L > 1$ then diverges.